# How to get all the links of all children of an element

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a element that I am able to locate:

`cy.get('[foo="bar"]')`

Now I'm trying to locate all the `a` elements within said element:

`cy.get('[foo="bar"] a')` this should give me all the elements that have the parent (or grandparent foo, and is `<a>`.

However, this only seems to select one element (that is parent foo and a), not all the elements, since I'm only getting one href saved.

This is what I use to save the results:

```
cy.get('[foo="bar"]').invoke('attr', 'href')
            .then((hrefs) => {
            cy.writeFile('./cypress/downloads/results.txt', hrefs)
        });
```

How do I select all the children, that are `<a>`, of `[foo="bar"]` and then how do I extract all of their href attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the step `.invoke('attr', 'href')` is just returning the first, see [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of matched elements

So, maybe

```js
cy.get('[foo="bar"] a')
  .then($els => {
    const hrefs = [...$els].map(el => el.getAttribute('href'))
    cy.writeFile('./cypress/downloads/results.txt', hrefs)
  })
```